# PBR, Viewport more quality than openGL render

Tags: rendering, opengl, versions

Im using Clément Foucault's latest PBR Blender build and I noticed that what I see in the viewport does not appear on the OpenGL render and they are not similar.
What might be the problem?

[image: Comparison between OpenGL and PBR Viewport Render]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind yall, i discovered it on my own

turns out that if you check the option for color management it produces the same effect to the viewport as it does to the openGL render. so the editing gets easier now
[image]